# DAT file manipulation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a delimiter separated dat file that I'm looking to manipulate. Below is what it looks like at the start:

```
'Field1'|'Field2'|'Field3'|'Field4'|'Field5'
'George'|'June'|'11'|'1943'|'Yes'
'Steve'|'May'|'17'|'1905'|''
'Jerry'|'March'|'01'|'1993'|'Yes'
```

Field 5 I will consider to be my "wiping" field. So, let's say if Field 5's value is "Yes", then wipe all other fields that the user selected. I essentially want to have the user select the "wipe" field, have the user select the "to be wiped" fields, and it will export a new DAT file.

For example, the user says wiping field = Field 5
The "to be wiped" fields are Field 2 and Field 3
Once complete, the script should also remove the wiping field altogether

The output should look like as follows:

```
'Field1'|'Field2'|'Field3'|'Field4'
'George'|''|''|'1943'
'Steve'|'May'|'17'|'1905'
'Jerry'|''|''|'1993'
```

I've been working with the csv module but I'm having a difficult time. Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend using `pandas`

Comment: Is that really the data structure in your dat file or your attempt to show a table? And how should a user 'select' any field there, how does your code look like so far? Please post a 1:1 sample of the first few lines of the file and your code, which produces your problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
from csv import DictReader, DictWriter, QUOTE_ALL


def solution(*, infile, outfile, wiping_field, fields_to_wipe=()):
    with open(infile, 'r') as in_fh:
        reader = DictReader(in_fh, delimiter='|', quotechar="'")
        fieldnames = reader.fieldnames

        if wiping_field not in fieldnames:
            raise ValueError('wiping field must be in fieldnames')
        if any(field not in fieldnames for field in fields_to_wipe):
            raise ValueError('all fields to wipe must be in fieldnames')

        result = []
        for line in reader:
            current = dict(line)
            if current[wiping_field] == 'Yes':
                for field in fields_to_wipe:
                    current[field] = ''
            current.pop(wiping_field)
            result.append(current)

        fieldnames.remove(wiping_field)

        with open(outfile, 'w') as out_fh:
            writer = DictWriter(
                out_fh,
                delimiter='|',
                fieldnames=fieldnames,
                quotechar="'",
                quoting=QUOTE_ALL
            )
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerows(result)
```

Output:

```
In[3]: with open('test.dat', 'r') as f:
  ...:     print(f.read())
  ...: 
'Field1'|'Field2'|'Field3'|'Field4'|'Field5'
'George'|'June'|'11'|'1943'|'Yes'
'Steve'|'May'|'17'|'1905'|''
'Jerry'|'March'|'01'|'1993'|'Yes'

In[4]: solution(
  ...:     infile='test.dat',
  ...:     outfile='output.dat',
  ...:     wiping_field='Field5',
  ...:     fields_to_wipe=('Field2', 'Field3')
  ...: )
In[5]: with open('output.dat', 'r') as f:
  ...:     print(f.read())
  ...: 
'Field1'|'Field2'|'Field3'|'Field4'
'George'|''|''|'1943'
'Steve'|'May'|'17'|'1905'
'Jerry'|''|''|'1993'
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This is really helpful. Do you mind if I take a look and get back to you? Sorry, I'm very new to programming

Comment: hey it's giving me an error: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'fieldnames'

Comment: @Tom I wrote/tested the script (with the output shown in the answer) using Python 3.6.5. My first guess would be that you modified the script from `csv.DictReader` to `csv.reader`. If you didn't modify the script, I would need more information about the input file you used and parameters you passed to the function which resulted in this error.